# R add all combinations of three values of a vector to a three-dimensional array

Tags: r, arrays

I have a data frame with two columns. The first one "V1" indicates the objects on which the different items of the second column "V2" are found, e.g.:

```
V1 <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C")
V2 <- c("a","b","c","d","a","c","d","a","b","d","e")
df <- data.frame(V1, V2)
```

"A" for example contains "a", "b", "c", and "d". What I am looking for is a three dimensional array with dimensions of `length(unique(V2))` (and the names "a" to "e" as `dimnames`).

For each unique value of `V1` I want all possible combinations of three `V2` items (e.g. for "A" it would be `c("a", "b", "c")`, `c("a", "b", "d"`, and `c("b", "c", "d")`.

Each of these "three-item-co-occurrences" should be regarded as a coordinate in the three-dimensional array and therefore be added to the frequency count which the values in the array should display. The outcome should be the following array

```
ar <- array(data     = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,1,0,1,0,2,0,0,2,2,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,
                         0,0,1,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,
                         0,1,0,2,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                         0,2,2,0,1,2,0,1,0,1,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,
                         0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
            dim      = c(5, 5, 5),
            dimnames = list(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
                            c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
                            c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")))
```

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering about the 3D symmetry of your result. It took me a while to understand that you want to have all permutations of all combinations.

```
library(gtools) #for the permutations

foo <- function(x) {
  #all combinations:
  combs <- combn(x, 3, simplify = FALSE) 
  #all permutations for each of the combinations:
  combs <- do.call(rbind, lapply(combs, permutations, n = 3, r = 3)) 
  #tabulate:
  do.call(table, lapply(asplit(combs, 2), factor, levels = letters[1:5]))
}

#apply grouped by V1, then sum the results
res <- Reduce("+", tapply(df$V2, df$V1, foo))

#check
all((res - ar)^2 == 0)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works very well in that example. However, in practice I have about 1,000,000 unique values in V1 and about 600 different items in V2, which creates a 600 x 600 x 600 table. At least my computer was unable to finish that task, even with a reduced set. Are there any other space-saving options to retain the same information (maybe in another format (e.g. a data frame with one row for each permutation - leaving out empty permutations)

Comment: Well, the number of permutations of combinations explodes quickly if the input vectors are large. You can easily calculate yourself how large it gets. I'd say this is basically impossible to solve with such large input. If you still want to try, you need a compiled language and parallelization.

Comment: I also think you could better utilize the symmetry if you use a compiled language (and thus `for` loops).

Comment: res <- setDT(df)[,CJ(unique(V2), unique(V2), unique(V2)), V1][V1!=V2 & V1 != V3 & V2 != V3,
                                                             .N, .(V1,V2,V3)][order(V1,V2,V3)]

Comment: It worked that way. I already used this crossjoin (CJ) to get the pairwise count of each combination of two V2 items. I just tried to add the third dimension and it works.

Comment: Feel free to add your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use the crossjoin `CJ()` to retain the pairwise count of all combinations of two different V2 items

```
res <- setDT(df)[,CJ(unique(V2), unique(V2)), V1][V1!=V2,
    .N, .(V1,V2)][order(V1,V2)]
```

This code creates a data frame `res` with three columns. `V1` and `V2` contain the respective items of `V2` from the original data frame `df` and `N` contains the count (how many times `V1` and `V2` appear with the same value of `V1` (from the original data frame `df`).

Now, I found that I could perform this crossjoin with three 'dimensions' as well by just adding another `unique(V2)` and adapting the rest of the code accordingly.

The result is a data frame with four columns. `V1, V2, and V3` indicate the original `V2` items and `N` again shows the number of mutual appearances with  the same original `V1` objects.

```
res <- setDT(df)[,CJ(unique(V2), unique(V2), unique(V2)), V1][V1!=V2 & V1 != V3 & V2 != V3,
    .N, .(V1,V2,V3)][order(V1,V2,V3)]
```

The advantage of this code is that all empty combinations (those which do not appear at all) are not considered. It worked with 1,000,000 unique values in `V1` and over 600 unique items in `V2`, which would have otherwise caused an extremely large array of 600 x 600 x 600